# CONAN ERROR: Conanfile defined package 'name', set_name() redundant

Tags: python, package, conan

I am unable to install a conan package due to the following error
ERROR: Conanfile defined package 'name', set_name() redundant

Instead of name in the recipe, I set the name through set_name() function. and it is not set/overwritten in the recipe anywhere else. This package has some dependencies which have their own name and versions.
I dont understand the root cause of this error or where to start debugging

Can someon assist with it?
Thanks

Comment: Fixed:

I was using the version 1.21.1  After upgrading the conan version , I dont get the error.!

Comment: Great that you upgraded and made it work! As a suggestion, it is better if you can provide in the question more details, like the OS, the Conan version, a very simple *conanfile.py* file and the command you are using that will fire the issue. That really helps readers to understand what is happening. You can also ask questions in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, specially if it is more a discussion/conversation.

Comment: Sure, will take care of it next time onwards. Thanks for sharing the github link